# Svg doesn't open from a blob storage

Tags: javascript, svg, blob, zip.js

I am writing a web app that's supposed to open a svg from a zip using the zip.js library

```html
<img src="" type="image/svg+xml" id="v">
```

Changing the image type in the html code doesn't seem to resolve the issue. When I open the blob link it has the svg code so that isn't the case either.

```js
document.getElementById("v").src = blobURL;
```

This is the code snippet responsible for setting the image source to the url

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: I also tried every possible combination of objects in html and it still doesn't work
`<img src="your.svg"/> 
<object data="your.svg"/> 
<iframe src="your.svg"/> 
<embed src="your.svg"/> 
<div style="background:url(your.svg)"></div>
<svg>       
<image xlink:href="./pic/v.svg" id="v" class="image"/>    
</svg>
`

Comment: Please add the code showing how you're unzipping the file and creating the Object URL.  Most likely zip.js doesn't set the correct file type when creating the blob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I solved it
I just made a XML request

```js
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open('GET', blobURL);
    client.onreadystatechange = function() {
    document.getElementById("vector").innerHTML = client.responseText;
    }
    client.send();
```